# JavaScript confirm popup not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file which is part of a basic Content Management System. Inside this file I have a table which contains a "Delete" link in every row.

What I am trying to do is create a choice popup in a javascript function of which I call when the link is clicked.

My function code (which appears in the head part of my php file) is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function delete(skillID)
{
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if(answer == true)
    {
        window.location.href = "process/deleteRecord.php?skillID=" + skillID;
    }
}
```

The code which calls this function is below:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:delete({$rowSkills['skillID']})\">Delete</a></td>";
```

The problem is that the box doesn't even popup, so the function isn't called properly.

Can anyone help?

*If there are any other details you need to know please let me know.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something else :

```
echo "<td><a href=\"process/deleteRecord.php?skillID={$rowSkills['skillID']}\" onclick=\"return(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'));\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, great idea, this doesn't seem to work either, it stops the page displaying :(

Comment: Yes I've got it working, it was those damn speech marks and "/ for quotes, I've got it working now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "onClick" attribute, try that :

```
echo "<td><a href=\"\" onClick=\"delete($rowSkills['skillID'])\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Thanks for the help, that definitely makes sense^ but for some reason it has stopped my page from appearing at all, maybe there is a syntaxx error somewhere?

Comment: I believe the attribute is "onclick" with a lowercase c instead.. however that doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, my mistake sorry, it's "onclick" and not "onClick"